# highcharts - inconsistent number of yAxis gridlines

Tags: highcharts

can someone explain why number of yaxis gridlines is less in exported svg rather than in the browser version? Is this happening because of margin update? if so, why it updates margin, but leaves old number of gridlines, shouldn't it be updated as well? 

 
Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sabira/r0zvouyp/

Thank you in advance!

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart:{
    events: {
      load: function(){
      const chart = this;
        const {title, yAxis} = chart;
                setRightDy(title);

      const ticks = chart.yAxis[0].ticks;
      let topTick = null;
      for(let tick in ticks){
        if(ticks[tick].isLast)  {
        topTick = tick;
        }
      }
      const tickY = ticks[topTick].label.xy.y;
      const extraMargin = chart.plotTop-tickY + 10;
      const currentMargin = chart.title.alignOptions.margin;

      chart.title.update({
        margin: currentMargin+extraMargin
      }, true, false, false)
      }
    }
  },
    title: {
        align: 'left',
        text: `
        <span class='titleText' style="font-weight: 500; font-size: 12.6px; font-family: Retina; fill:black"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </span><br>
       <span class='dekText' style="font-size: 8.4px; fill: black; font-weight: 300; font-family: Retina"> Integer quis pharetra tellus. Cras tincidunt libero id dignissim convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</span><br>
<span class='subdekText--strong' style="font-weight: 500; font-size: 8.4px; font-family: Retina; fill:black">Sed aliquam ligula in pretium lobortis.</span>
       <span class='dekText' style="font-size: 8.4px; fill: black; font-weight: 300; font-family: Retina"> Integer quis pharetra tellus. Cras tincidunt libero id dignissim convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</span><br>
<span class='subdekText--strong' style="font-weight: 500; font-size: 8.4px; font-family: Retina; fill:black">Sed aliquam ligula in pretium lobortis.</span>

        `,
        widthAdjust: -40,
        margin: 20,
    },
    exporting: {
    scale: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
      labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 0,
        y: -4
      }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments - your case is more complicated, but I think that a good solution is do also a yAxis.tickAmount update with a current ticks amount to do not calculate them again while the chart is initializing for exporting. See:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wju68av5/

```
chart.update({
  title: {
    margin: currentMargin + extraMargin

  },
  yAxis: {
    tickAmount: chart.yAxis[0].tickPositions.length
  }
}, true, false, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you are struggling to is that you set the new margin after the initial load, which changes and animate the chart. However, the export server renders a new chart with a options which you used to set but without loading the load callback, because there is no delay time to do it.

Why don't you just set the calculated margin as a fixed value in the **title.margin** object and set the wanted amount of ticks to get it? The visual output is the same.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/owr6f7z2/

```
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      x: 0,
      y: -4
    },
    tickAmount: 7
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount

If this answer wouldn't fit your requirements please describe more precisely what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Sebastian, thank you for your response! The main reason of doing update on load is that, because plotTop x-value same as —value of top xAxis gridline, but because in my scenario, top yAxis label positioned much higher than the top gridline I want margin to be calculated as if plotTop x-value is top yAxis label x- value (spacing[0]+height of title element + title margin = plotTop) So by knowing what plotTop is(which is possible only on load)  I can calculate the ‘extra title’ margin (line 45 in my fiddle). Unfortunately, I can’t specify number of wanted tickAmount beforehand (different data).

Comment: hope it makes sense!

Comment: Also, if the export server renders a new chart with 'before the load callback' options, why is margin still gets increased in the exported svg?

Comment: I am still working on your case it is not so easy to achieve, but back to your last question the main difference is that in browser you had defined container dimensions, meanwhile export takes default values